# How to a span tag before a li tag with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, html-lists, html

I am using the [List category post](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts) plugin in WordPress. I wanted to add `<span></span>` after a `<li>` because I'll be putting a bg image overlay in the span. So it will be like this: `<li><span> </span> </li>`

I'm trying to experiment with CatListDisplayer.php (line 87) of the said WordPress plugin because I notice that this is where the loop of the list happens.

```
$this->lcp_output .= '>';
$inner_tag = ( ($tag == 'ul') || ($tag == 'ol') ) ? 'li' : 'p';
```

I've tried adding this:

```
$this->lcp_output .= '>';
$inner_tag = ( ($tag == 'ul') || ($tag == 'ol') ) ? 'li' . 'span' : 'p';
```

But what I got is `<lispan>`. I've been trying different combinations now but still what I get are errors. Apologies, I barely know anything about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In file "CatListDisplayer.php" find private function lcp_build_post($single, $tag) - Line 179 and find in that function this (Line: 187):

```
$lcp_display_output = '<'. $tag . $class . '>';
```

and replace with this:

```
$lcp_display_output = '<'. $tag . $class . '>'.(( ($tag == 'ul') || ($tag == 'ol') ) ? '<span></span>' : NULL);
```

Enjoy. ;-)

Comment: Hi Ivijan, the span still didn't appear, but thanks so much for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated! :-)

Comment: My pleasure. I answered your question but are you sure you're looking at the correct part of the code? I not had time to review the entire plugin. Please you flip all the PHP files so if you see something like that put in comment.